# Pass Javascript Array Value to HTML

Tags: javascript

My Javascript array Contents looks like below

```
Order[0] = Order ID
Order[1] = Unused
Order[2] = Payment Amount
```

I want to Pass the following parameters oid=Order[0] & amt=Order[2] to the following

```
<img src="https://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_conversion?advid=K123456&oid=12345&amt=123.45" width=1 height=1>
```

I have written this code but it doesnt work

```
<script>    document.write('<img src="https://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_conversion?advid=K539002&oid=+%Order[0]%+&amt=+%Order[2]%" width=1 height=1>')</script>
```

Not sure what is the problem in it

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) In what context have you tried it in?

Comment: JavaScript, to the best of my knowledge, doesn't interpolate variables in strings; so you'd need to close the string, concatenate the variable, and then reopen the string, eg: `'The order id is: ' + order[0] + '.';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the values properly:

```
<script>
    document.write('<img src="https://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_conversion?advid=K539002&oid=' + Order[0] + ' &amt=' + Order[2] + "' width="1" height="1" />')
</script>
```